# Adding HTML tags to text that doesn't have any

Tags: jquery, html

So I have a page being populated from a database and the data being inserted looks like this. There is paragraphs that don't have a html tag.

```
<h1>Title</h1>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
<ul>
  <li>One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <li>Three></li>
</ul>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
<h2>Title 2</h2>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
<h1>Title 3</li>
```

How do I wrap these paragraphs in `<p></p>` using jquery?

The optimal result would be

```
<h1>Title</h1>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
<ul>
  <li>One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <li>Three></li>
</ul>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
<h2>Title 2</h2>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
<h1>Title 3</li>
```

Comment: Are the title/headers and lists from the db? Does the db return the above html literally?

Comment: Yes all of that is being populated into a div. I know we should fix the database but that is not an option right now.

Comment: Is the structure always the same (h1,p,ul,p,h2,p,h1) or is it random?

Comment: Surely if you're inserting the `<h1>`,`<ul>` (and so on) tags then you could add `<p>` tags? Could we see your code for fetching/sending this data, please?

Comment: @depperm its random but the same tags (h1, ul, paragraphs)

Comment: Could you show what you want the resulting HTML to look like with the `<p>` tags added?

Comment: @jaunt there is about 50,000 records and I am a not a backend dev so I wouldn't know how difficult it would be to create a query to add <p> to the database.

Comment: I know the question is about using jquery, but shouldn't this be done serverside while generating the html output, in whatever server language is used?

Comment: I'm confused as to why the texts have no `<p>` tags in the first place. You're fetching the data from a database, so then surely you could change the input data to prevent this problem from happening in the first place?

Comment: Alongside the marked answer (jQuery select and wrap textNode), you can use this to get rid of the extra paragraphs that were created from the newlines: $('p').each(function(){if($(this).text().trim() == ''){$(this).remove();}});